# regular expression to match only json output

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract valid JSON from various output. Sometimes it is:

```
[
{
"parameter1" : "value1",
"parameter2" : "value2"
}
]
/*
bla bla
*/
```

Sometime it is different:

```
{
"parameter3" : "value3",
"parameter4" : "value4"}
/*
another blah
*/
```

BUT sometimes it has no comment section (valid JSON without /*).
So this multi-line string can not be parsed as JSON because of extended characters after data.
How can I get rid of this characters if they exist using re module in python 3?

I tried to use this regexp match

```
^((.|\n)*?)\/\*
```

but when there is no comment it is not working at all.

Comment: If there is either a comment or nothing after the JSON, you can try `^((.|\n)*?)\s*(?:\/\*|\Z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking for the first and last curly braces and use those, regex not needed.

```py
import json
main_data = """[
{
"parameter1" : "value1",
"parameter2" : "value2"
}
]
/*
bla bla
*/
"""
json_data = json.loads(main_data[main_data.find('{'):main_data.rfind('}')+1])
print(json_data)
```

output

```
{'parameter1': 'value1', 'parameter2': 'value2'}
```

You could also use the error message to get the location of extra characters in general which might work for more complex scenarios. [JSONDecodeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError) has properties that help doing this.

```py
try:
    json_data = json.loads(main_data)
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    if e.msg == 'Extra data':
        json_data = json.loads(main_data[:e.pos])
    else:
        raise e
```

### OLD

```py
try:
    json_data = json.loads(main_data)
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    error_message = str(e)
    if error_message.startswith("Extra data:"):
        json_data = json.loads(main_data[:int(error_message[error_message.rfind('(char ')+6:-1])])
    else:
        raise e
```

alternately use regex matching on the error message to make it clearer

```py
try:
    json_data = json.loads(main_data)
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    expected_error = "^Extra data: line \d+ column \d+ \(char (\d+)\)$"
    error_message = str(e)
    match = re.match(expected_error, error_message)
    if match:
        json_data = json.loads(main_data[:int(match.group(1))])
    else:
        raise e
```

Comment: thanks, but what if array contains several objects?

Comment: you could try matching by `[`, if that doesn't work then do `{`. If your comment contains these characters too, then you might have to use even more complex solutions.

Comment: great, I can just use json_data = json.loads(main_data[:main_data.rfind('/*')]) and it works in any cases.

Comment: @Vanomel added the code to handle more complex scenarios

Comment: It isn't necessary to parse the character position of the error from the error message. It is available as `e.pos`.